# How to solve $n$ in $5^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$5^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

I see that this holds true when $n$ is prime by Fermat's little theorem. However there could be few composite numbers, $n$ for which the congruence might hold true ? How to find them ?

I know how to handle problems involving the variable outside the mod, like, $2^{500}\equiv  x \pmod{5}$ etc...  but never dealt with the problems when the unknown is inside the mod itself. Any help is highly appreciated!

We have just started congruences chapter and I know basic congruence properties and Fermat little theorem. If possible, kindly avoid carmichael numbers/group theory/euler theorems as they are not covered yet. Thank you!

Comment: You are asking for a "nice" characterization of the Fermat pseudoprimes to the base $5$. That may be difficult. The smallest one I can think of is $n=124$.

Comment: As was pointed out by a comment now gone, I missed $n=4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, sorry, I have moved this comment with $n=4$ to the "answer" (although your comment is already an answer). Actually, Crandall and Pomerance also exclude $n=4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is help in terms of the integer sequences project. There Fermat pseudoprimes to the base $5$ have been found; see [here](http://oeis.org/A005936). The page gives some helpful references too, but a "nice" characterisation seems not to be available. The sequences starts with $4, 124, 217, 561, 781, 1541,\ldots $, so the smallest $n$ is equal to $4$.

Comment: I see that this problem is equivalent to pseudoprimes. I'll search further. Thank you so much :)